# Can I assume that this is a GMM?

Tags: normal-distribution, maximum-likelihood, gaussian-mixture-distribution, expectation-maximization

I'm trying to find the MLE for the parameters of the following distribution:

$$f(x) = a \ \mathcal{N}(\mu_a, 1) + \beta \ \mathcal{N}(\mu_\beta, 1)$$

Taking the log likelihood of this complicates things a bit. I know this is a common issue with mixed gaussians and is usually handled by viewing $a, b$ as latent variables and applying the EM algorithm. This allows the log to enter the sum, as the sample will either belong to the first or the second distribution, cancelling the other term.

For context this is the point that I'm talking about:

$$\log \mathcal{L}(\mu_a, \mu_b ; x) =  \sum\limits_{i=1}^{i=N} \log \left(a\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-\frac{1}{2}(x_i-\mu_a)^2} + b\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-\frac{1}{2}(x_i-\mu_b)^2} \right) $$

However, is it valid to do this? If the distribution is given as the linear combination of the gaussians, is it fair to say that each sample comes from one of the two Gaussians?

Comment: Its the same distribution. It makes no difference whether you perceive of it as a two component mixture or just a distribution that happens to have that particular pdf.